# Reporting Services unattended account login failure

Tags: reporting-services

I have a new 2008 Reporting Services server and report. The data source for the report is set to use Windows Integrated Security. When I try to run it I get

The report server has encountered a configuration error. Logon failed for the unattended execution account. (rsServerConfigurationError)

Using the account specified in the Execution Account in RS Config Manager I can log into the server and SQL Mgmt Studio although I don't have any rights to the database I'm reporting on. Any idea why I would get this error? What's it trying to log into?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the report server is trying to use the Unattended Execution Account to connect to the database specified in the report data source.

If the account specified does not have permissions to read data from that database then you can change your data source connection, e.g. choose "Credentials Not Required" and then add a username and password for the data source to the connection string. This is not ideal however, because the username and password will be visible to anyone with permission to edit the data source.

Ideally you need to either have permissions to the source database granted to the Unattended Execution Account or change your data source to use a different connection method, e.g. use Stored Credentials and specify an account with permissions to the source database (if you don't actually need the features enabled by setting an Unattended Execution Account, then you can remove it entirely).

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156302(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I wondered about that, which is why I made mentioned it didn't have access to the database. I didn't grant it access because the article states "Be sure to use an account that has minimum permissions". Let me try this out.